# Swift about view does not confirm to protocol "UITableViewDataSource"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
class showPageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    var records : [Record] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return records.count
}

func tableview(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    return UITableViewCell()


}

func tableView(_ tableVoew: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    if editingStyle == .delete{
        let record = records[indexPath.row]
        context.delete(record)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        do{
            records = try context.fetch(Record.fetchRequest())
        } catch{
            print("Failed")
        }
    }


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getData()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func getData(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do{
        records = try context.fetch(Record.fetchRequest())
    } catch{
        print("123")
    }
}
```

}

This is the code of my program, I am trying to make a to-do list app, but the error does not confirm to protocol "UITableViewDataSource" always appear, I try to find the solution, but nothing suitable for me, is anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a mix of Swift 2 and Swift 3 methods in your code. Your `cellForRow...` method is using the newer Swift 3 signature. You need to use the older Swift 2 compatible version.

I believe it is:

```
func tableview(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

Check all of the other table view data source and delegate methods and make sure they all use the Swift 2 compatible signatures and not the newer Swift 3 signatures.

Comment: Wait, isn't the `override` keyword necessary here?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov You only need `override` if the method is defined in the parent class. `UIViewController` doesn't define any of the table view methods.

Comment: Oh right, you don't use `override` for protocol method implementations

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov You do if you are overriding an implementation from a parent class (which is not the case here).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are mixing swift 2 and swift 3. Your methods should be like this:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

You have done several spelling mistakes in those methods, Please check above methods with yours